# Add a view/layout to a Map on OsmDroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I am working with osmdroid and I'm wondering if there is a way to "stick" a view on a map. The problem with the OverlayItem is that is impossible to change it without delete it. Delete and create another item is not energy-friendly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can add a child view to your mapview. mapview.addview(View, MapView.LayoutParams). If that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a geo-located View to the maps using `mapView.addView()` if you set the LayoutParams of your view to `MapView.LayoutParams`. In the LayoutParams you can set the location of the view.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed ;). It works !
Very great work on OsmDroid by the way !

Comment: I have a problem with that solution. When I zoom in or zoom out, the view move with the animation and it doesn't keep his position. While with ItemizedIconOverlay, markers are stuck on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you call a "view", but look at [OSMBonusPack Marker](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack): you can change most of its attributes without having to delete/recreate.

Comment: is this possible to add logo on MapView and bundle it as jar?